# CoreDataのNSPredicateで日付を検索する方法を教えて下さい

Tags: swift, coredata

例えばCoreDataで"Data"というエンティティを作成したとして、
その中にType：DateのAttribute、"day"を作成したとします。
そして特定の日付(時間は無視します)のdayを引っ張ろうと試みた時に、次のようなコードとなりました。

```
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let PersonContext: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
let PersonRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Data")
PersonRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = ?????", "day", ?????)
PersonRequest.predicate = predicate
var results: NSArray! = PersonContext.executeFetchRequest(PersonRequest, error: nil)</code>
```

5行目のlet predicateで、?????の部分にどのようなコードを打ち込んで
目的の日付を検索すれば良いのかわからず、困っています。
どうすれば、特定の日付をエンティティから引っ張ることが可能でしょうか。

説明不足かもしれませんが、分かる方がいらっしゃれば解説の程宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

```
let calendar :NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
let targetedDay :NSDate! = calendar.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 5, day: 12, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.day BETWEEN {%@ , %@}", targetedDay, NSDate(timeInterval: 24*60*60-1, sinceDate: targetedDay))
```

例えば、特定の`NSDate`を作って、そこからの24時間-1秒を`BETWEEN`で取るという手があります。`day`の`attribute`には、`SELF.day`を使います。

ミリ秒までデータがあるならば、`SELF.day >= %@ AND SELF.day < %@`で厳密に期間判定をした方が良いです。